# Capture and stream video using Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to capture video by webcam and convert it to RTMP Stream using AIR.But i'm not able to find any example like this.Is there any way to do like this?Please give me some examples to implement this.I'm new to ActionScript and i'm doing in ActionScript and i've seen the Camera api in ActionScript but it is not working may be i wrongly implemented.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       title="Hello Air Appp" >
    <s:Label text="Hello AIR" />

        <fx:Style> 
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"; 
        s|WindowedApplication 
        { 
            skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin"); 
            background-color:#999999; 
            background-alpha:"0.7"; 
        } 
    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var connection:NetConnection;
            private var outStream:NetStream;

            //device properties
            private var camera:Camera;
            private var microphone:Microphone;

            //video properties
            private var outVideo:Video;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                trace("In the frst fn");
                connection = new NetConnection();
                connection.connect("rtmp://0.0.0.0/TestApp"); 
                connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);
            }

            private function onConnected(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
                if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
                    setupVideo();
                }
            }
            private function setupVideo():void {
                //setup outgoing devices
                if (Camera.names.length > 0)  {
                    var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); // Get default camera. 
                }
                else 
                    trace("No Cameras Found");
                if(Microphone.names.length>0)
                    microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
                microphone.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,onMicStatus,false, 0, true); 
                function onMicStatus(event:StatusEvent):void {
                    if (event.code == "Microphone.Muted") 
                        trace("Microphone access was denied."); 
                }
                //setup outgoing stream
                outStream = new NetStream(connection);
                outStream.attachCamera(camera);
                outStream.attachAudio(microphone);
                outStream.publish("DemoVideo1","live");

                //setup outgoing video and attach outgoing devices
                outVideo = new Video(250,250);
                outVideo.attachCamera(camera);
                addChild(outVideo);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 1):

At last i found a way to capture video from webcam and stream it.As i said i want it it AIR so i created a ActionScript class to work this.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.Responder;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**0...
     * @author BECKER Christophe
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        //
        public var vid : Video;
        public var cam : Camera;
        public var bt : Sprite;
        public var txt : TextField ;
        public var microphone : Microphone;
        private var connection:NetConnection;

        private var outStream:NetStream;
        public var nc : NetConnection;
        public var responder : Responder;
        private var inStream:NetStream;
        private var inVideo:Video;
        public function Main() {
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.client = { onBWDone: function():void{ trace("onBWDone") } };
            connection.connect("rtmp://Ipaddress/TestApp"); 
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);

        }
            private function onConnected(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {

            if(Camera.names.length>0){
                cam = Camera.getCamera();
                cam.setMode(640, 480, 15);
            }
            if(Microphone.names.length>0)
                microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

            outStream = new NetStream(connection);
            outStream.attachCamera(cam);
            outStream.attachAudio(microphone);
            outStream.publish("DemoVideo1","live");


            vid = new Video(300, 300);
            vid.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(vid);

//          inStream = new NetStream(connection);
//          inStream.play("DemoVideo1");

//          inVideo = new Video(250,250);
//          inVideo.attachNetStream(inStream);

//          addChild(inVideo);



                            }
        }


        private function metaDataHandler(meta : Object) : void {
            if (vid) {
                vid.width = meta.width;
                vid.height = meta.height;
            }
        }

    }
}
```